# Change in internal energy for isothermal process

Tags: thermodynamics

> A gas expands isothermally against a constant external pressure of $1\ \mathrm{atm}$ from a volume of $10\ \mathrm{dm^3}$ to a volume of $20\ \mathrm{dm^3}$. It absorbs $800\ \mathrm J$ of thermal energy from its surrounding.
> The change in internal energy is:

I came across this question and my doubt is, for isothermal process, $\Delta U=0$ ( change in internal energy) for ideal gas is zero right? Then how can we calculate $\Delta U=0$ here, assuming the gas to be ideal?

Is the error with the question or am I missing something?

Comment: $\Delta U=0$ for an isothermal process on an ideal gas.

Comment: So the gas in question is not ideal?

Comment: The process is irreversible, see the P-V graph, ext. P is at 1 but volume changes by 10 units implying a straight line. After this observation, proceed with dq=dw+du

Comment: @Anindya does it mean this is not a isothermal process?

Comment: No, it is isothermal, just irreversible....

Comment: There are two types, one is reversible process and one is irreversible, it can be for adiabetic process as well, i.e. irreversible adiabetic process and reversible adiabetic process exist seperately.

Comment: refer here https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(Fleming)/03%3A_First_Law_of_Thermodynamics/3.03%3A_Reversible_and_Irreversible_Pathways

Comment: I suppose the question didn't specify the gas is perfect, so delta U need not be 0. If you compute for w and the delta U turn out to be 0 then the gas is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It must not be an ideal gas.  This is irrespective or whether the process is reversible or irreversible.   That is the only possible conclusion.  Otherwise the amount of heat received would adjust  until it was equal to the work done.